# Update array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, svelte

I am trying to do something similar to a shopping cart, where initially there is a series of products that I load with an array of objects.

```
products = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Product1",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Product2",
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Product",
        },

];
```

I show the list of products with svelte like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 row grid">
    {#each products as product}
        <div class="card mt-2 g-col-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5>{product.name}</h5>
                        <button
                            on:click={addProduct(product.id)}
                            class="btn btn-primary">Add Product
                        </button>
                        { "0 products"}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

And through the function addProduct() I update the array **inventory** with the product id and the number of units of that product

```
let inventory =[];
const addProduct = id =>{
        
        let qty = 0;
        if(inventory.find(element => element.id === id))
        {
            qty = inventory.find(element => element.id === id).qty
            inventory=inventory.filter(element => element.id !== id)
            inventory.push({id:id,qty:qty+1});

        }
        else{       
        inventory.push({id:id,qty:1});
        }
        
    }
```

Where I don't know how to set it up is in each product, where it now says { "0 products"}, update it dynamically as the user adds each of the products

Thanks a lot !

Comment: why do you keep looking up the same thing? `const item = inventory.find(element => element.id === id); if (item) console.log(item.qty);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand with `{ "0 products"}` you want to display the number of items in the inventory. You could do this by replacing it with

```
{inventory.find(element => element.id === product.id)?.qty ?? 0} products
```

[Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) used

Besides the fact that you want to [assign `inventory` to itself](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-2-assignments-are-reactive) after you made an edit like pushing an item, so that a re-render is triggered, there's a logical problem in `addProduct()`. If there's already an element, you don't want to push another one, but edit the existing, which gives

```
function addProduct(id) {
        const element = inventory.find(element => element.id === id)
        if(element) {
            element.qty += 1
            inventory = inventory
        }
        else{       
            inventory.push({id:id,qty:1});
            inventory = inventory
        }
    }
```

While this would work - see [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/fb740435263f4e468b5fa90c629f417f?version=3.46.6) - I would consider making inventory an object instead of an array, because it was a bit 'quicker' to check for entries and edit them, compare this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/bcbdd661d4a74e61aded63c4fc8be895?version=3.46.6) (the entries could always be easily iterated using `Object.entries/.keys/.values(inventory)`)

```
<script>
    import {products} from './products'

    let inventory = {}

    function addProduct(id) {
        const entry = inventory[id]
        if(entry) {
            entry.qty += 1
            inventory = inventory
        }
        else{       
            inventory[id] = {qty:1}
            inventory = inventory
        }
    }
</script>

<div>
    {#each products as product} 
    <h5>{product.name}</h5>
    <button on:click={() => addProduct(product.id)}>
        Add Product
    </button>
    {inventory[product.id]?.qty ?? 0} products
    {/each}
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! The truth is that she has helped me a lot. One last question, what is the reason for putting inventory = inventory;

Comment: That's needed so that Svelte's reactivity is triggered. Have a look at this link https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-2-assignments-are-reactive (If the answer solved your question, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark on the left side of it)